# Angular 4 input range filter Json

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I am creating a search pipe in angular4 which filter company team size from Json Data with range input from 0 to 100. The range filter is not working, I am new to typescript and angular4, please help I did some basic code but I am not getting the logic.

The Range Pipe -

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'range'
})
export class CheckboxPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    console.log('args', args);
    return args
            ? value.filter(sal => { return sal.team })
            : value;
  }

}
```

Range Input box -

```
0 <input type="range" min="0" max="100" 
        [(ngModel)]="team" name="team" /> 100
```

List to filter -

```
<div *ngFor="let joblist of jobList | range: team">
    {{joblist.team}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I solved the range filter problem, its actually not that hard. Here it is -

The slider range pipe -

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'range'
})
export class RangePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(teamVal: any, teamFil?: any): any {
        console.log('teamFil', teamFil);
        return teamFil
         ? teamVal.filter(person => person.team >= teamFil) 
         : teamVal;
    }

}
```

The Range slider -

```
<span>0</span>
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" [(ngModel)]="sliderValue" />
<span>100</span>
```

The slider value in component -

```
sliderValue: number = 0;
```

Data to filter with range slider -

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let joblists of jobList | range: sliderValue">{{joblists.team}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `transform()` to this,

```
transform(value: any, team?: any): any {
return (team || team === 0)
        ? value.filter(sal => { return sal.team })
        : value;
}
```

See if it fixed the issue.

**UPDATE:**

Not exactly sure on this but I guess the `ngModel` may not be getting a proper value since the `input` `type` is of `range`. Could you try this instead?

```
0 <input #rangeInput type="range" min="0" max="100" [(ngModel)]="team" name="team" /> 100
<div *ngFor="let joblist of jobList | range: rangeInput?.value">
 {{joblist.team}}
</div>
```

So I added a template reference variable `#rangeInput` and used that to pass the value of that `control` to the `pipe`.

If that also didn't work, try changing the `team === 0` check in the `return` of the `transform()` to this `team === '0'`. (Treating the `value` as a `string` instead of a `number`).

Comment: no sir, it is still the same. I got tutorial from this (http://jilles.me/ng-filter-in-angular2-pipes/) but it is based on angular 2, made some changes on this.

Comment: I'm not sure if the pipes are significantly different in v4 from v2, if not the same. What changes did you have to make to accommodate for v4?

Comment: Hello Sir, it is giving the following error - Cannot read property 'value' of undefined. Any suggestions?

Comment: On what line are you getting this?

Comment: This one - <div *ngFor="let joblist of jobList | range: rangeInput.value">

Comment: sorry, change it to this: `<div *ngFor="let joblist of jobList | range: rangeInput?.value">`

Comment: The real reason you're getting the value of undefined error is because the life cycle of the component: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

When ngOnChanges() executes the rangeInput value is undefined; you can solve this either by adding a default empty value to the rangeInput in the component's constructor, or using the elvis operator (the ?) in the template as @amal suggested.

Comment: hello @amal I solved the problem, check my answer, its working fine. :)